# How to show lock screen notification in Android 4.4?

Tags: android, notifications, android-4.4-kitkat

I want to show notification on lock screen, but they are available since Android L. Are there libraries that allow to show lock screen notification on Android 4.4? For example via widgets.

Answer (score 0):

There's an app in play store- NILS Lock Screen Notifications, However special custom notifications can be obtained in 4.4, by tweaks!

Comment: I know about this application, but I'd like to realize something similar in my application withour 3-rd party apps.

Comment: Why not integrate the relevant lock screen package of 4.4+ to 4.4. Android Studio is ready to help.

Answer (score 0):

Lock screen notifications are only available since Android 5.0 (Lollipop). However you can use 3rd party apps - such as "NiLS - Lock screen notifications" from Google Play to be able to get notifications on top of your stock lock screen without replacing your lock screen app.

Comment: I know about this application, but I'd like to realize something similar in my application withour 3-rd party apps.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old, but in case it is still relevant to anybody--you can do this.

settings / my device / lock screen / lock screen widgets / owner information / [type the message you want to be shown]